# Why do EFB and AGM start/stop batteries need registering / programming? How does that work?

Tags: battery

I understand that EFB and AGM car batteries, used in start/stop vehicles, need some kind of registration or programming when they are replaced.

- Is this always the case? Can you skip this step if you replace the battery with an identical one?
- How does this step work and how much does it change from car to car? (I have a Volkswagen). Does it mean pushing some buttons? Does it require connecting a laptop to the car?
- Is it something that any mechanic could do or something that only an authorised dealer can do, e.g. maybe because there is some kind of software encryption and only authorized dealers can do it?
- In my area, authorised dealers are all closed because of the lockdown, but there are mobile mechanics who can replace tires and batteries. They explicitly say they have the "kit" to program an AGM battery. Does this sound credible? Or would they do a half-baked job because, say, every manufacturer requires very different kit for this?
- The Volkswagen manual doesn't say anything, other than "bring it to a Volkswagen dealer"; the philosophy is that even replacing the screen wash should be done by an authorised dealer who will charge for labour, otherwise very bad and dangerous things will happen! :)

Comment: If you want to work on your car then get something other than a VW - you seem to have this complaint about the dealers every time you post.

Comment: You must have a lot of time on your hands if you always come back with these comments that add nothing to the discussion. FYI I don't want to "work on my car", I want to pay someone else to replace the car battery for me, and I just want to understand how the process works. That is not "working on my car"

Comment: These comments are not constructive on either side.

Comment: "A start-stop battery is a part of the on-board electronics and is linked to the vehicle electronics via the Battery Management System (BMS) and the battery sensor (EBS). The control unit detects the number of starts and the energy flow, monitors the state of charge and controls charging. When a start-stop battery is replaced, the energy management s system is programmed by the diagnostic device in the workshop.">>>>>>https://batteryworld.varta-automotive.com/en-gb/how-do-i-change-an-efb-or-agm-battery

Comment: Also this>>>>https://www.yuasa.co.uk/info/technical/start-stop-vehicle-battery-replacement-warning/

Comment: Moab, thanks for the links. I should have mentioned I had actually seen those links. What I still don't understand, though, is how that works. Do you have to connect a laptop to the car and run some specific software? Do you push a couple of buttons and simply choose EFB or AGM, 60Ah or 70Ah, etc? What kind of equipment is required to do it? Do you happen to know?

Comment: All batteries degrade over time and the computer tracks the degradation and adapts the charging routine to charge the degraded battery at the proper charge rate. When you install a new battery you have to tell the computer that you've installed a new battery so it doesn't continue charging using the old routine--the old routine on a new battery will shorten its life. The reset requires a high end scan tool that works with VWs. The tech connects the tool and clicks on the new battery box. Call the shops that are open. IF they say they can do it on a VW, then take it there

Comment: Do I also need to somehow tell the computer if I have charged the battery myself, with a charger like an Optimate Ctek Noco etc, or would the computer recognise that automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I actually found quite a few answers in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JRQCWNzguic&t=569s). The guy explains that you need to input the "BEM code"; some manufacturers put a sticker with this code on the battery, but not all. This code tells the car how to properly manage the battery and is entered using a device that looks like a tablet, connected to the car.

There is also the VCDS software, which I think is a software you can install on a Windows laptop; an example is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IJAScg6JrYI)

These videos answer how a new battery is registered to the car, but I'll confess I still haven't fully understood why it's needed and if it really has to be so convoluted. I must say it does remind me of how corporations fight the "right to repair" (google *Louis Rossmann right to repair*), forcing you to use only official channels for even the most banal type of repair. Yes, the videos talk about how the car must be told that there is a new battery, but is entering a specific code which not all batteries have, and entering it with a very specific tool the only feasible way to do so?